# Could I detect user deletion using context-menu through javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contextmenu

My application having a content-Editable DIV, How could I detect deletion action from context-menu?

Comment: `detect deletion` you mean `cut/backspace`...etc? right.

Comment: I have already handled "cut, copy, paste" from Context-menu also keyboard shortcuts (Ctrl+x, Ctrl+v, Ctrl+c, Delete key)

Comment: i am not able to see `Delete` in the `context-menu`. So what are you expecting from your question? i mean i don't get you now.

Comment: "Delete" is allowed in Firefox and IE context-menu.
Selecting desired text by keyboard arrows and then right-click on selected text.

Comment: Well in that case you might check for target's content length to check what has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `oncut` event on the element itself, but ***which option is selected from the `context-menu` is not possible***.

```js
$('[contenteditable]').on('cut', function(e){
   alert(e.type);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable='true'>add more</div>
```

Comment: Could we have something like that but for deleting.
 $('[contenteditable]').on('delete', function(e){
})

Comment: @AhmedMostafa no! there is no such event in DOM api. instead you can use Mutation Observers but it has limits to version 11 of IE.